# Putting an inactive Meteor app to sleep on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 server using nginx

Tags: meteor, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have multiple Meteor apps running on a single DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 droplet, using nginx.

Is it possible to have a similar result to Heroku's free app hosting where an app 'goes to sleep' after not being accessed a certain amount of time and then wakes up after being accessed again?

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense to put your droplet into sleep. You will be charged for it's usage no matter it is running or not.

Comment: @Tdm I'm not talking about putting the droplet to sleep but the Meteor app that's running on it. Only mentioned the type of server for context.

Comment: by default Heroku's Dyno (free plan) goes to sleep after 30 min of inactivity. and wakes up when hit by user.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I know. And?

Comment: Why would you want that? It will slow you down when it tries to wake up, and you don't save any money.